# Change TextView Color pressing a button

Tags: android, dynamic, colors, textview

I'm trying to create an activity entirely by java code. The goal here is to create an Activity that fills up itself  by previous activity. It's a shop list activity. 
The user add itens in the previous activity and when he ask to show the complete list the activity above will be generated.

The problem here is, I want to set red as the initial color of the textviews with the itens names, and when the user clicks on then, they change their color to green.
But when I click it the aplication force close with the message indexoutofbounds exception.
Could someone helps me?

```
public class Listdinamiccor extends Activity  {


Bundle recebendoparametros;
int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listdinamiccor);
    Intent parametro = getIntent();
    recebendoparametros = parametro.getExtras();
    int j = recebendoparametros.getInt("i");


    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);
    final TextView[] tvarray = new TextView[j];
    for (i = 0; i < tvarray.length; i++) {
        String chave = "chave"+i;
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tvarray[i] = new TextView(this);
        tvarray[i].setText(""+recebendoparametros.getString(chave));
        tvarray[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tvarray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int click = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*if (click == 0) {
                    tvarray[i].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else {
                    tvarray[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }*/
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Listdinamiccor.this);
                alert.setTitle("dinamico");
                alert.setMessage("eu sou muito dinamico");

            }
        });
        ll.addView(tvarray[i]);
    }

    this.setContentView(sv);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listdinamiccor, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your logcat messages pls. Indexoutofbounds is to do with your array and not with the textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your loop has completed executing, i is now set to tvarray.length -- your onClick handler doesn't "remember" the value of i, it simply does what you tell it to, which is to setTextColor on tvarray[i], and i is now out of bounds.

One way to solve it is to do this above your setOnClickListener line:

```
final TextView me = tvarray[i];
```

And then change your onClick method to call me.setTextColor instead of tvarray[i].setTextColor.

Also, I wouldn't recommend hanging onto the int i outside of your loop - I'm assuming you moved the member to the parent class so that your current code compiled, but in general you don't want to use for loop indexes outside of the for loop (this exception is one such reason).

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your View v to a TextView inside your onclick listener instead of using the instance your creating in your array like this:

```
tvarray[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int click = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (click == 0) {
                ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
               ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Listdinamiccor.this);
            alert.setTitle("dinamico");
            alert.setMessage("eu sou muito dinamico");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yup :) Thats how I usually do manipulations on dynamically created views where a click can change the look of said view.